# Visual Studio 2015 C# rename horribly slow

Tags: visual-studio-2015

Any time I use the C# Edit|Refactor|Rename function, applying the changes is horribly slow - like 30 seconds or more slow. Sometimes an "updating files" popup appears while this is happening.

Everything else on the machine is fast and responsive. The C++ equivalent is also just fine. Is anyone else seeing this problem? Any solution?

EDIT:

Per magicandre1981's suggestion I ran an ETW trace. I also attached another instance of the VS debugger to the one I was using to see if that yielded up anything interesting.

I found two interesting things:

1. The slowdown is exponential - initially it's fast but by the 10th time you've used it it's taking 10 seconds, by the 20th time it's taking a minute or more.
2. There's an exception being thrown inside a Delegate.Remove method. (Specifically inside System.MulticastDelegate.RemoveImpl.) So I'm guessing something is getting hooked up and then never removed.

Basically this call stack is being hit thousands of times:

`mscorlib.dll!System.MulticastDelegate.DeleteFromInvocationList(object[] invocationList = {object[4096]}, int invocationCount = 3569, int deleteIndex, int deleteCount = 1)
mscorlib.dll!System.MulticastDelegate.RemoveImpl(System.Delegate value)
mscorlib.dll!System.Delegate.Remove(System.Delegate source, System.Delegate value)
Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.EditorFeatures.dll!Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Editor.Implementation.InlineRename.InlineRenameSession.OpenTextBufferManager.SpansChanged.remove(System.Action value = {Method = {System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo}})`

Both the ETW trace and simply breaking in with the debugger hit this call stack.

So... more info but I haven't figured out why yet.

ANOTHER EDIT:

Aaand I just did what I should have done in the first place: disable extensions to see if it makes any difference. Sure enough the performance problem went away. I narrowed it down to a particular extension - I'll contact the author and see if they can fix it.

Comment: capture a ETW race of the issue.Install the Windows Performance Toolkit from the Windows 10 SDK (https://dev.windows.com/en-us/downloads/windows-10-sdk), run WPRUI.exe select CPU, DISK, VirtualAlloc and under scenario .Net. Start a trace, do the rename and after this is finsihed go to the WPRUI, stop the tracing, now go to the fodler where you stored the EL file. Compress the ETL + the ngenpdb folder!!! into a zip/RAR (to educe the size a lot) and uplod the zip to OneDrive and post a link here.

Comment: @magicandre1981 thank you - that helped.

Comment: which extension was the cause?

Comment: [Abmes Syntax Highlighter](https://github.com/abmes/SyntaxHighlighter). I bugged it.

Comment: See answer at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22304636/visual-studio-incredibly-slow-when-renaming-files/43592740#43592740