# Visual Studio 2015 C# rename a control horribly slow

Tags: refactoring, visual-studio-2015

Refactoring/renaming a control in Visual Studio Community 2015 (either in the form designer code file, or through the graphical designer) is very slow and each change uses an additional 60 MB of RAM memory.

I did read the [Visual Studio 2015 C# rename horribly slow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22304636/visual-studio-incredibly-slow-when-renaming-files) post, but that person's solution does not apply to me, because I did not add any extensions: this is Visual Studio "right out of the box".

- open the project: 170 MB (the Designer is closed)
- rename a control: 350 MB (in the code file)
- revert the naming: 420 MB
- rename a new control: 500 MB

After 2 or 3 renamings, I have to quit the application and open it again.

Many people must have encountered this, yet I don't see much discussion about it.

I just switched from VS 2010, which did not have this problem.

EDIT: I restarted the computer, no other programs running: same problem. Now Window 7 tells me: "Microsoft Visual Studio is busy / Microsoft Visual Studio is waiting for an internal operation to complete. ... "

Are there any solutions or workarounds?

Comment: I have to battle this constantly too, never seen a good answer. It's awful and leading to crap naming practices as I've not got time to wait 30 seconds every time. Poor show VS.